# useInteractiveGuideline not working correctly in Angular nvd3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to use angular nvd3 to draw a line chart with Focus, but I'm facing a problem using the interactiveGuideline `useInteractiveGuideline : true,`, in fact it uses only the first and last point in the selection and it doesn't interact with my chart. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WlCn5Q?p=preview) for more details.
any idea to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

you must call .reverse() on each of your 4 chart parts, then its working for me.
Here I have done it for just one of them, and guidelines works for only it:

```
.reverse()
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n0p2f74NsnmbiRhLhMO0?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like if the data isn't in ascending order the interactive guidelines are messed  up. As @MojioMS suggested, reversing the sequence or providing data in ascending order fixed the problem for me.